# Connection to Wakanda Server has been closed

Tags: wakanda

When I run just a basic project in Wakanda I have this message:

> Sending command to Wakanda Server has failed while switching to no debugger. Connection to Wakanda Server has been closed.

I don't know why, somebody can help me?

Comment: The debugger is enabled ?

Comment: No I am in No debugger (performance), When I am in debugger mode I have this message: "Sending command to Wakanda Server has failed while getting breakpoints. Connection to Wakanda Server has been closed.

Comment: Have you tried to kill the server from the task Manager and run again ?

Comment: If you have any breakpoints remove them

Comment: Thanks a lot, just kill the server from the task Manager and run again work

Comment: You are welcome